# indexedDB Error createObjectStore when used inside onMount fn with sveltekit

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

First time trying to use indexedDB. Attempting to create an objectStore but I'n getting the error shared below. I've never used indexeddb in sveltekit before so I have no idea how to fix it.

I created a basic sveltekit using the steps outlined in their doc. In index.svelte, I imported onMount fn and typed the following

import { getContext, onMount } from 'svelte';
import { detach_before_dev } from 'svelte/internal';

```
onMount(async () => {

   const request = indexedDB.open("okdb", 1)
 request.onerror = (event) => {
    console.error('Database error:' , event);
};

request.onsuccess = (event) => {
       console.log("onsuccess log :", event)

       let db = event.target.result;

// create the Contacts object store 
// with auto-increment id
let store = db.createObjectStore('Contacts', {
    autoIncrement: true
});


};



})
```

I get the following error:

```
  index.svelte? [sm]:42 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The database is not running a version change transaction.
    at IDBOpenDBRequest.request.onsuccess (http://localhost:5000/src/routes/index.svelte:121:19)
```

I see the db created in my dev tools application tab but I get the error above every time I try to create the createObjectStore. It seems like a straightforward object creation procedure and it shouldn't give any error.

Any idea why or how to fix it? I don't need to import app/evn browser from the sveltekit, do I?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the doc, it is clear that onupgradeneeded has to include new version to trigger the creation of the ObjectStore.

Increase the db version

```
 const request = indexedDB.open("okdb", 2)
```

It will trigger onupgradeneeded which will allow you to create ObjectStore like this:

```
let customerData = [
    {ssn:"444-44-4444",name:"Bill",age:35,email:"bill@company.com"},      
    {ssn:"555-55-5555",name:"Donna",age:32,email:"donna@home.org"},
    {ssn:"666-66-6666",name:"Simone",age:10,email:"Simone@home.org"}
  ];

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
     
    let db = event.target.result
    console.log("onupgadeneeded log :", event.target.result)


    //adding new objectstore

    var objectStore5 = db.createObjectStore("customers5",{keyPath:"ssn"});
      objectStore5.createIndex("name","name",{unique:false});
      objectStore5.createIndex("email","email",{unique:true});
       for(var i in customerData){
         objectStore5.add(customerData[i]);
      }
```

Then from there you can perform the rest of the crud operations.

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["customers"], "readwrite");
// Do something when all the data is added to the database.
transaction.oncomplete = event => {
  console.log("All done!");
};

transaction.onerror = event => {
  // Don't forget to handle errors!
};

var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("customers");
customerData.forEach(customer => {
  var request = objectStore.add(customer);
  request.onsuccess = event => {
    // event.target.result === customer.ssn;
  };
```

});